# Hierachichal Data MySQL Query

Tags: php, mysql, hierarchy, hierarchical-data

I have this level of hierachichal data

```
A 
|_ B
|_ C
|  |_ D
|  |_ E 
|_ F
```

database structure

category id, parent_id, category name

I want MySQL Query that give result in this matter

```
A     NULL NULL NULL
F     B     C   NULL
NULL  NULL  D   E
```

My main concern in this query is to display child data under it's parent

Comment: Not really possible with MySQL. That's something better done with a client-side transform/data structure.

Comment: you should be looking at this : http://explainextended.com/2009/03/17/hierarchical-queries-in-mysql/ . Obviously you might have to do some processing at application level in php

Comment: I don't have level field in database. How can we manage this in PHP?

Comment: if you can put your all detail It might be helpful e.g table structure + some test data + output format. Please read the  linked resource. Don't expect you will understand it so quickly . It will take a day or so to understand it .

Comment: I want output or display in this matter https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/orgchart

Comment: check this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/943507/mysql-parent-child-query?rq=1

Comment: Need to add level field for this one?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15041/discussion-between-ankit-shah-and-sakhunzai)

Comment: sorry @AnkitShah chat not possible

Comment: MySQL is not well suited for this task. If the use of MySQL is not compulsory you could try with a NoSQL database. For instance, CouchDB is good at storing information trees.

Comment: @mvillaress: another alternative would be a (modern) DBMS that does support recursive queries.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name thank you for the information. I'm very interested in this topic. Which DBMS supporting recursive queries would you recommend me?

Comment: @mvillaress: nearly all others: PostgreSQL, Oracle, Firebird, DB2, SQL Server, Sybase, H2, Teradata, Vertica. Search this site for "recursive common table expression" or any "hierarchical" question not involving MySQL.